# Override original CSS with media query

Tags: css

I created an article header css code, from a post, I got solutions to how to fix the header from overlapping by changing

```
#Article_Header2 {
height: 48px;
font: normal normal normal normal 16px / normal 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
margin: 0px;
}
```

to

```
#Article_Header2 {
min-height: 48px;
font: normal normal normal normal 16px / normal 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Changing to min-height: 48px works perfectly for mobile but doesn't work for desktop. I would like to change that to only apply when it's on a mobile device. 
May I ask where am I going wrong. I tried the folling.

```
@media (max-width:767px) {

    body #Article_Header2 {
        min-height: 48px;
        font: normal normal normal normal 16px / normal 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
        margin: 0px;
    }
}
```

When that's applied, the min-height is applied to desktop as well. I'm wondering how can I set min-height: 48px only on mobile and set height 48px on anything else.

Comment: look at the phones and handhelds section in [this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since height and min-height are different properties, one doesn't overrides the other.

```
#Article_Header2 {
font: normal normal normal normal 16px / normal 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
margin: 0px;    
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
#Article_Header2 {
height: 48px;        
}
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
#Article_Header2 {
min-height: 48px;    
}
}
```